Creating a custom simulation object: A Delta Robot in Anylogic

I am trying to get this robot included in a custom library in anylogic.I have researched some materials on the Anylogic Website: Adding Custom Simulation Objects.
But it does not provide any contents on the mechanism of the object.
I do understand, I have to upload the base dae object, the arms, and the end effector separately.
I have also worked out the calculations needed to determine the angles, and position of each joints to move the end effector as desired.
I am looking forward, to moving the joints in anylogic. Because with X, Y, Z co-ordinates the whole objects move. As you can see, the joints should be fixed and along the direction the other end must rotate. How can I achieve that?

Suggest you distill the key issue you phase (relative vs absolute coordinates) into a simpler question, showing a simple setup, what you tried and what you expect
